# Changing drop Down Text in JAVAFX after the page is loaded

Tags: javafx-2, javafx-8

How do I change the text size in the drop down in java FX? Currently it's not coming out correctly as per the css. Looks fine when I run the url through a browser. However the drop down text sizes are coming out very small when the url is loaded and viewed in JAVA FX.

Here is my code:

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws InterruptedException {
    stage.setTitle("test");
    Pane stackPane = new Pane();
    Browser browser = new Browser();
    stackPane.getChildren().add(browser);
    Rectangle2D primaryScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
    webScene = new Scene(stackPane, primaryScreenBounds.getWidth(), (primaryScreenBounds.getHeight()-50), Color.web("red"));
    webScene.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("main.css").toExternalForm());
    stage.setScene(webScene);
    stage.show();
}

public Browser() {
    //apply the styles
    getStyleClass().add("browser");
    String url = "http://localhost:8000/myapp";
    webEngine.load(url);
    getChildren().add(browser);
}
```

Comment: You may provide some code ...

Comment: Updated the sample code.